# how to use setState to update a property of a list element?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of download tasks as datasource for `ListView`. After the list is created, I'll start all tasks and when any task is done, I'll update `task.isDone` property so changes are reflected to UI. How do I do this with `setState`?:

```dart
// My list of tasks used in ListView
List<Task> _tasks;

Future<void> onLoaded() async {
    // Load initial tasks.
    var tasks = await loadTasks();
    // Set state.
    setState(() {
        _tasks = tasks;
    });
    // Start tasks.
    _tasks.map((task) async {
      // When any task is done, update the state and UI.
      await startDownload(task);
      setState(() {
        // Can I do this?
        task.isDone = true;
      });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can start your task when the first `setState` finished and this means after the ui rebuild, so try this:

```
Future<void> onLoaded() async {
    // Load initial tasks.
    var tasks = await loadTasks();
    // Set state.
    setState(() {
        _tasks = tasks;
    });

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) { // <---- add this
        // Start tasks.
        _tasks.map((task) async {
          // When any task is done, update the state and UI.
          await startDownload(task);
          setState(() {
            task.isDone = true;
          });
        });
    });
}
```